# Gem to generate slugs similar to Limax in NPM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rubygems, slug

I'm looking for a Rails gem that generates slugs for strings and also knows how to handle asian/russian/etc characters (anything non-english).

This is what I typically use in a Node app, is there something similar for Rails?

---

https://github.com/lovell/limax

```
var slug = require('limax');

var latin = slug('i ♥ latin'); // i-love-latin
var cyrillic = slug('Я люблю русский'); // ya-lyublyu-russkij
var pinyin = slug('我爱官话'); // wo3-ai4-guan1-hua4
var romaji = slug('私は ひらがな が大好き'); // ha-hiragana-gaki
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails has [parameterize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-parameterize) method that replaces special characters in a string with an ASCII approximation so that it may be used as part of a pretty URL. Default approximations are provided for Western/Latin characters, e.g, “ø”, “ñ”, “é”, “ß”, etc.

```
> 'Bonjour à vous'.parameterize
=> "bonjour-a-vous"
> 'Viel Glück'.parameterize
=> "viel-gluck"
```

You also can make custom transliterations in `config/locales` like

```
# config/locales/de.yml
i18n:
  transliterate:
    rule:
      ü: "ue"
      ö: "oe"
```

A list of some languages can be found at https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/transliteration

---

For non-latin languages, as far as I know, there are no gems support all of them. But for one specific language, it might be possible.

For example:

- Russian: [russian](https://github.com/yaroslav/russian)
- Chinese: [chinese_pinyin](https://github.com/flyerhzm/chinese_pinyin)
- Japanese (kana only): [romaji](https://github.com/makimoto/romaji)

Comment: Thank you, but I found an all-in-one solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using Stringex, you can get readable url's from many different languages.

```
gem 'stringex', '~> 2.6'
```

---

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_url :title, url_attribute: :slug
end
```

Now everytime a Post is updated, it generates the slug from the title attribute and saves it to the slug field.

```
"simple English".to_url => "simple-english"
"it's nothing at all".to_url => "its-nothing-at-all"
"rock & roll".to_url => "rock-and-roll"

"$12 worth of Ruby power".to_url => "12-dollars-worth-of-ruby-power"
"10% off if you act now".to_url => "10-percent-off-if-you-act-now"

"kick it en Français".to_url => "kick-it-en-francais"
"rock it Español style".to_url => "rock-it-espanol-style"
"tell your readers 你好".to_url => "tell-your-readers-ni-hao"
```